# Custom Entity field of type long_text not storing values

Tags: 8, entities

I created a entity.

```
$fields['supplemental'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('text_long')
                ->setLabel(t('Supplemental'))
                ->setDescription(t('Answer description.'))
                ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
                    'label' => 'hidden',
                    'type' => 'text_default',
                    'weight' => -3,
                ))
                ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
                    'type' => 'text_textfield',
                    'weight' => -3,
                ))
                //->setRequired(TRUE)
                ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
                ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

And I'm saving data into this entity's field like

```
$mcq = Mcq::create(array(
           'supplemental__value' => $value->supplemental,
            'supplemental__format'=>'basic_html',
        )); 
$mcq->save();
```

**Issue is** all fields gets populated except of type '`text_long`'. Am I missing something or there is any other way of populating entity field values.

Answer (score 3):

After realising few minutes later, the column name should be `supplemental` not `supplemental__value`.

I was mapping content by looking into database columns which was wrong.